# Shopify Calculated Product Link

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Produce a link within Shopify to another product that is related. The Handle name is

- Product: handle-name
- Product to link to: handle-name-sample

Example:
Product: fabric-name
Product to link to: fabric-name-sample

I have manually created a link within the template but would like to automate this in some way. Ideas around options are:

- Put the destination handle in an attribute which is specified in the upload file (Matrixfy)
- Pull back the handle of the product and append sample on the end in the current template

Any suggestions of how I would do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You got the pattern. Create a metafield resource that connects one product to another, and just surface the connected product in your template. Simple, easy to maintain, and curated! Makes sense.

Comment: you are creating 2 products right -> prod and prod-sample

Comment: @hardiksatasiya yes I'm creating 2 products one for the product and the sample. The reason is the sample price is impacting the price of the product.

Comment: @davidlazar created a metafield that links a product. I have gone into the Theme CMS to insert a dynamic source and the product metafield isn't appearing. Have tried a numeric metafield which does appear. Is there compatibility issue displaying product metafields?d

Comment: `<a href="{{ card_product.url }}-sample"` just append `-sample` at the end

Comment: @HardikSatasiya Tried to add the code via the template interface however I got the error:

card_product.url is invalid.

Also tried to add the shortcode into the product description which also didn't work. Is there anything else I need to be doing when adding the shortcode to a template?

Comment: if possible share me access of store so i can fix it up for you.

Comment: Hi @hardiksatasiya emailed you. Let me know.